# Ubuntu cannot play Chinese DVD

Tags: video, 16.04, dvd, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I have Ubuntu 16.04 with all restricteds, addons, libs, etc installed and regionset China. I can play most DVDs from various sources and regions. But I cannot play any DVD that has been burned in China locally: copies of foreign dvds can play, but China specific cannot. The o/s will not even see a Chinese dvd in the drive, and gives error no disk found.  Obviously, I need a codec or library or whatever.  Has anyone had this problem and have you solved it? Please share your knowledge. Where can I find the codecs, apps, libs, etc ?  Thanks.

Comment: OK first of all , you need to check if you have two packages installed `regionset` and `libdvdread4` . What does `apt-cache policy libdvdread4 regionset` tell you ?

Comment: **OTHER USERS** : the question asks about *specific problem* related to media playback on *supported* release of Ubuntu. **DO NOT DOWNVOTE OR VOTE TO CLOSE THIS QUESTION**

Comment: Hi Serg and thanks for reply.   Yes, installed, and here is output...                    $ apt-cache policy libdvdread4 regionset
libdvdread4:
  Installed: 5.0.3-1
  Candidate: 5.0.3-1
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.3-1 500
        500 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
regionset:
  Installed: 0.1-3
  Candidate: 0.1-3
  Version table:
 *** 0.1-3 500
        500 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: ok, you have both packages , from what i see.  Typically dvd drive is designated as `/dev/sr0` . What happens if you do `sudo regionset /dev/sr0` ?

Comment: Thanks again for reply.    1/ For a readable dvd, regionset returns the number "6", which is correct for China.      2/ The dvd in question is not readable using Ubuntu.  Regionset requires a readable dvd, and is thus useless in my case.

Comment: BTW, the dvd will play perfectly in a Macbook that has been purchased in China and loaded with Chinese version o/s and apps.  So, the dvd is in fact readable and intact. Using handbrake for mac, the dvd can be converted to a m4v with no troubles. Thus my problem is specific to Ubuntu/Linux.  Thanks.

Comment: update:  the China dvds can play in a Win7 machine with no problems. Using VLC, the video codec is mpeg-1/2[mpgv], the video decode is Planar420YUV, and audio codec is A52[akaAC3].  I cannot understand why Ubuntu 16.04 cannot read and play these dvds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the final solution by trial and error, after my laptop gave me clues (it has win7 and 15.10 loaded), and after weeks of frustrations without help. I loaded everything I could find for dvd: gxine; libxine-all; everything for ffmpeg; python3dvd; quicktime -lib and -util. I reinstalled the libdvd-read -css2 etc as a precaution. This enabled 16.04 to at least read the dvd and attempt to play it. VLC gave me an error reading about blocks, which is a cryptic way of stating the drive itself may be a problem. Seems my sata drive was too old and could not process the blocks. Bought a new drive and problem now solved. I hope my troubles and solution may benefit others. p.s. I think the quicktime is the main solution.